# How to get the expected value and variance of $\log{||x||^2}$ where x $\sim$ Student t-distribution

Tags: expected-value, t-distribution

In the following paper [A Novel Parameter Estimation Algorithm for the Multivariate t-Distribution and Its Application to Computer Vision](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-15552-9_43.pdf), under section 3.2, the authors state some results for the expected value and variance of the logarithm of the squared norm $||x||^2$, of the multivariate Student-t variable $x$.

I know that the equation (10) from the paper is derived from a property of elliptically contoured distributions as presented for example [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.02428.pdf), but I don't know how to derive the results they presented.

I tried solving the integral:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \log{||x||^2} \frac{2||x||^{p-2}\Gamma(\frac{\nu + p}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{p}{2}) (\alpha \nu)^{p/2}} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{\alpha \nu} ||x||^2 \right)^{-\frac{\nu + p}{2}} d||x||^2$

but I was unable to solve it.

Can you please guide me through the procedure that yields the results obtained in the paper, both for the expected value and for the variance?

Comment: Try writing the $t$ random variable in terms of a standard normal and an independent chi-squared.

Comment: @BigBendRegion Ah, indeed! I will try that and see if I can get the result! Thank you for your comment and advice!

Comment: @BigBendRegion That was brilliantly simple! Thank you again! I wonder why they included the equation (10)... I really thought that the result was only obtainable through the knowledge of this distribution!